# ProgressDialog.show stuck while handling Otto event

Tags: android, progressdialog, otto

There are two activities in my app, `CreateOrderActivity` and `PaymentResultActivity`.  A 3rd-party payment app is used to finish the payment.

```
CreateOrderActivity -> 3rd-party payment app -> PaymentResultActivity
```

And I want to send the result back to `CreateOrderActivity` so I use Otto:

```
CreateOrderActivity -> 3rd-party payment app -> PaymentResultActivity
         ^                                                |
         |-------------------- Otto <----------------------
```

Here is the code:

```java
// PaymentResultActivity

bus.post(new PaymentFinishedEvent(resultCode));
finish();
```

```java
// CreateOrderActivity

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    bus.register(this);
}

@Subscribe
public void onPaymentFinished(PaymentFinishedEvent event) {
    checkPaymentResult(event.resultCode);
}

private void checkPaymentResult(int resultCode) {
    Log.i("checkPaymentResult", "1");
    Request request = buildCheckingPaymenResultRequest();

    Log.i("checkPaymentResult", "2");
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Checking...", true);

    Log.i("checkPaymentResult", "3");
    request.execute(new Listener() { ... });
}
```

When I run the app and the payment is finished, `PaymentResultActivity` is fired, event is posted on bus and method `checkPaymentResult` runs successfully. But when I place a new order in the app **again** and finish the payment, the event will also be posted, but the app will just get stuck and will not check the result.

I added the three lines of debug logging into the code above to find out at which step the app is stuck, and it shows out that `1` and `2` are printed in the Android Monitor, but `3` will never be printed, which means the `ProgressDialog.show` could not execute successfully and the program just get stuck there. I cannot understand why could the code fails just at the second try.

By the way, the launch mode of `PaymentResultActivity` is `singleTop`, which is required by the 3rd-party app.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when Otto fires an event back to `CreateOrderActivity`, the activity is still paused in the background and cannot commit any operations on the UI (window, view, etc.). Thus I add a flag in `CreateOrderActivity` to tell whether it needs to check the result of the payment:

```
public class CreateOrderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    private boolean shouldCheckPaymentResult = false;

    ...
}
```

And in the event handler just set the flag to `true`:

```
@Subscribe
public void onPaymentFinished(PaymentFinishedEvent event) {
    if (event.resultCode == PaymentFinishedEvent.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
        shouldCheckPaymentResult = true;
    }
}
```

The final step is to carry out the checking in `onResume()`:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (shouldCheckPaymentResult) {
        shouldCheckPaymentResult = false;
        checkPaymentResult();
    }
}
```